# FloatingActionButton should be visible without scrolling (in CollapsingToolbarlayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

How to have a FloatingActionButton visible when initially entering displaying a screen and without scrolling/collapsing the toolbar with a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

This screenshot shows the default behavior with the collapsing toolbar and fab which I want to change to have the fab initially visible regardless of the scroll state.

The Fab is in a Fragment which is attached to an Activity.

[image: default behavior]
Layout Code of the Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ActivityTitle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/default_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_swipe_refresh_list"/></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout Code of the Fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<de.aposync.team.widget.view.ContainerSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_container_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="96dp"/>

</de.aposync.team.widget.view.ContainerSwipeRefreshLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/view_progress_bar_group"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    tools:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert""/></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Edit**
The answer from Jantzilla provides a working solution, but requires the FAB to be moved from the fragment to the activity. Is there any solution which doesn't require the fab to be moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of this on [Github](https://github.com/romainz/CoordinatorLayoutSample). The app can also be sampled on the [Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zanon.tests&hl=fr) store. I recently used this as a reference for a project of my own.

**The Code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

/**
* Created by romain on 15/10/15.
*/
public class ScrollCollapseLargeToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private View mFab;
private int mFabTranslationSize = 0;
private boolean mFabIsVisible = true;

public static void start(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScrollCollapseLargeToolbarActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll_collapse_large_toolbar);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String toolbarTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.sample_collapse_scroll_toolbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(toolbarTitle);

    mFab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nested_scrollview);
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                animateFab(false);
            } else {
                animateFab(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void animateFab(boolean show) {
    if (show && !mFabIsVisible) {
        //Show
        mFabIsVisible = true;
        mFab.animate().translationY(0);
    } else if (!show && mFabIsVisible) {
        //Hide
        mFabIsVisible = false;
        if (mFabTranslationSize == 0) {
            int margin = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mFab.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin;
            mFabTranslationSize = mFab.getHeight() + margin * 2;
        }
        mFab.animate().translationY(mFabTranslationSize);
    }
}
}
```

**The XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_expanded_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it like this working earlier the day. Unfortunately that makes the separation into activity and fragment impossible. I moved the CoordinatorLayout in the fragment into a frame layout and the fab from the CL into the FL and set the layout_behavior on the CL ... unfortunately this doesn't work for me and the layout breaks :/ I wish there was a simple flag to let the FAB ignore any scrolling behavior ...